# Why isn't my USB C to HDMI cable that supports monitor extender working as expected?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display, adapter, usb-c

I have an IdeaPad Flex 5 15ITL05 and then I bought a [triple monitor extender](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CDW485BJ). The USB C to HDMI cable that came with the monitor extender works fine. One of the monitors works.

Then I bought a USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter and then another USB C to HDMI cable to get the other monitor to work but I am still getting no signal.

I also tried USB 3.0 docking station but I am still only able to get just one monitor to work. I think the problem is the type of USB C to HDMI cable I bought.

Does anyone have any idea why it's still not working?

Comment: What triple monitor extender?

Comment: Sorry i meant Triple Laptop Screen Extender
Here's the link to the item [Product](https://www.amazon.com/APILDELLA-Extender-Portable-Monitor-Plug-play/dp/B0CDW485BJ?th=1).

Comment: @JDDoe - [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: have you tried swapping the monitors and cables around?  Do they work in different positions?

Comment: Wow, what a monster. It’s important to note that many display connection cables are not reversible in direction. Which cables, exactly, did you buy? This display uses a proprietary HDMI to USB-C cable (note the direction: HDMI goes in, USB-C goes to the display.)

Comment: A USB 3 cable isn’t necessarily identical to a Type-C cable. Furthermore, Type-C HDMI mode must be supported by the hardware, which does not typically include the USB 3.0 ports. The type-C ports must also support video transmission.

Comment: @Keltari the usb c to hdmi cable that came with the device works on both monitors. its also an unbranded usb c to hdmi cable so i have no where they got that cable from.